# insert/update/delete rows in table(t1) by by insert/delete/update takes place in table2

Tags: database, oracle10g

My requirement as below.

I have table(T1) and Table (T2) In oracle database.

when I insert/delete/update in table T2 automatically same actions should be in table t1.

if I insert row in the table T2,same row should be insert in T1.

same for delete and update action.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Triggers. In your case there will be two triggers one for each.